# 'sensorVal' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

Why does this not work?

```
    const int sensorPin = A0;
    const float baselineTemp = 20.0;
    void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    for(int pinNumber = 2; pinNumber<5; pinNumber++){
    pinMode(pinNumber,OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(pinNumber, LOW);
    }
    } 
    void loop(){
    int sensorval = analogRead(sensorPin);
    Serial.print("Sensor Value:");
    Serial.print(sensorVal);
    float voltage = (sensorVal/1024.0) * 5.0;
    Serial.print(", Volts: ");
    Serial.print(voltage);
    Serial.print(", degrees C: ");
    float temperature = (voltage - .5) * 100;
    Serial.println(temperature);
    if(temperature < baselineTemp){
     digitalWrite(2, LOW);
     digitalWrite(3, LOW);
     digitalWrite(4, LOW);
    }
     else if(temperature >= baselineTemp+2 &&
      temperature < baselineTemp+4){
      digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(4, LOW);
    }  
     else if(temperature >= baselineTemp+4 &&
      temperature < baselineTemp+6){
      digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(4, LOW);
    }
     else if(temperature >= baselineTemp+6){
      digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
    }
     delay(1);
    }
```

When I use this code to measure temperature, I get the error in the title. Why? I have an Arduino Uno, and checked that my code is exactly the way it's supposed to be.

Comment: You declared `sensorval` and then used `sensorVal`. I assume you meant to declared it as `sensorVal` (uppercase V). Just fix that typo.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of errors are not hard to find and fix. You just need to take 5 more minutes before posting a question on StackOverflow.

```
int sensorval = analogRead(sensorPin);
```

should be:

```
int sensorVal = analogRead(sensorPin);
//        ^
```

Neeeext.